# Как принять и отобразить данные из формы с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, form, submit

На html странице есть форма. Если в форму ввести данные и нажать принять, в блоке `<div id="foo"> </div>` должны отобразиться параметры, например так:
`firstname=Mickey&lastname=Mouse`.
Как это сделать?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="frstname">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="lastname">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="foo"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо добавить обработку отправки формы.
Учтите, что если не выполнить отмену стандартного обработчика (e.preventDefault(); или return false;), то форма отправится и страница перезагрузится сразу после вывода сообщения в div.

Также в данном случае, возможно, нет необходимости использовать форму (так как в таком виде она все равно не отправляется). Возможно, вам больше подойдет ajax запрос, с помощью которого вы впоследствии отправите эту строку на сервер.

```js
$('form').bind('submit', function(e) {
  var firstName = $(this).children('input[name="firstname"]').val();
  var lastName = $(this).children('input[name="lastname"]').val();

  $('#foo').text('firstName=' + firstName + '&' + 'lastName=' + lastName);

  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  First name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="frstname">
  <br>Last name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="lastname">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="foo"></div>
```